# Botones de edición en CRUD usando Datatables - server side

Tags: php, mysql, datatables, server-side-rendering

miren tengo el siguiente código el cual estoy usando DATATABLES con el cual muestro mi contenido paginado y unas opciones de busqueda, pero me falta algo y, es que necesito también agregarle en la columna ACCIONES, un par de botones de editar y eliminar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver me falta completar esa columna. A continuación dejo el script para cargar los datos con DataTable y tambien el archivo server.php el cual contiene los datos necesarios para la conexión a mi db.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#tbl-contact thead th').each(function () {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html(title+' <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar" />');
        });
        
        var table = $('#tbl-contact').DataTable({
                "scrollX": true,
                "pagingType": "numbers",
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": "server.php",
                order: [[2, 'asc']],
                columnDefs: [{
                    targets: "_all",
                    orderable: false
             }]
        });

        table.columns().every(function () {
            var table = this;
            $('input', this.header()).on('keyup change', function () {
                if (table.search() !== this.value) {
                       table.search(this.value).draw();
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Div donde voy a mostrar el contenido de la tabla.

```
  <!-- Contenido -->         
<div class="datatable-container">
    
    <table name="tbl-contact"  style="text-align:center;" id="tbl-contact" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">   

        <thead>
            <tr>
                
                <th>DNI / ENCARGADO</th>
                <th>ÁREA</th>
                <th>DESCRIPCIÓN</th>
                <th>TIPO</th>
                <th>CANTIDAD</th>
                <th>FECHA</th>
                <th>ACCIONES</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        
    </table>
</div>


  <!-- Fin Contenido --> 
</div>
```

Este es mi archivo server.php

```
<?php

      // DB table to use
   $table = 'tabla_reportes';

// Table's primary key
 $primaryKey = 'id_entrega';


 // Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
 // The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
 // parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
  // indexes
  $columns = array(
  array( 'db' => 'dni', 'dt' => 0 ),
  array( 'db' => 'area',  'dt' => 1 ),
  array( 'db' => 'descripcion',   'dt' => 2 ),
  array( 'db' => 'tipo', 'dt' => 3,),
  array( 'db' => 'cantidad','dt' => 4,),
  array( 'db' => 'fecha','dt' => 5,),



);

// SQL server connection information
 $sql_details = array(
 'user' => 'root',
 'pass' => '',
 'db'   => 'kardex',
 'host' => 'localhost'
);




require( 'vendor/DataTables/server-side/scripts/ssp.class.php' );

 echo json_encode(
   SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Agrega al emmiter las opciones para crear, editar, y eliminar de la siguiente manera

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    buttons: [
        { extend: 'create', editor: myEditor },
        { extend: 'edit',   editor: myEditor },
        { extend: 'remove', editor: myEditor }
    ]
} );
```

> La opcion editor es por si tienes un editor custom o indicarle si usaras el theme por default fijate mas en la documentación [Haz click para ver la documentación.](https://datatables.net/reference/button/edit#:%7E:text=The%20edit%20button%20type%20is%20added%20to%20DataTables,the%20edit%20%28%29%20method%20to%20edit%20that%20data.)

Answer (score 0):

debajo de `array( 'db' => 'fecha','dt' => 5,),`
coloca:

```
array( 'db' => 'id_persona', 'dt' => 12,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) { 
        return '<a class="open-Modal1 btn btn-warning pull-center  btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-id="'.$row['id_persona'].'" data-nombres="'.$row['paterno'].' '.$row['materno'].' '.$row['nombre1'].' '.$row['nombre2'].'" data-inst="'.$row['institucion'].'"data-cargo="'.$row['cargo'].'"data-cel="'.$row['celular'].'"  data-target="#modalEditarDatos" title="EDITAR"></a>'; 
        } 
    )
```

aqui llamo a un modal desde la columna en caso mio 12 me funcionó perfecto

[image: codigo en sublime text]